# How do I get the name of the entity/table and the record number for adding audit?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, audit

I'm trying to do an audit method for my system using the EF DbContext. I overwrite the SaveChanges event. However, I have two difficulties where I need help. I've read a lot on the internet and here at the StackOverflow but I still couldn't reach a solution. Can you help me?

1) I can't get the actual name of the table when I'm adding a record. When I add the record to a table simply comes the name "Object". The other operations with the name normally.

2) After entering the registry I would like to have the registry ID to put in the audit log. Any suggestions?

I anticipate an apology if the questions are so obvious the answers but I really don't understand how to proceed.

```
public partial class coletasEntities : DbContext
{
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();

        foreach (var change in ChangeTracker.Entries())
        {
            if (change is auditoria || change.State == EntityState.Detached || change.State == EntityState.Unchanged)
                continue;

            //Pega o nome da tabela
            var entityName = change.Entity.GetType().Name;
            //var entityName2 = change.Entity.GetType().BaseType()

            if (entityName == "auditoria") continue;

            // Get the Table() attribute, if one exists
            //TableAttribute tableAttr = change.Entity.GetType().BaseType.Name;
            TableAttribute tableAttr = change.Entity.GetType().GetCustomAttributes(typeof(TableAttribute), false).SingleOrDefault() as TableAttribute;

            // Get table name (if it has a Table attribute, use that, otherwise get the pluralized name)
            //string tableName = tableAttr != null ? tableAttr.Name : ((TableAttribute)tableAttr[0]).Name;
            //string tableName = tableAttr != null ? tableAttr.Name : change.Entity.GetType().Name;
            string tableName = tableAttr != null ? tableAttr.Name : change.Entity.GetType().BaseType.Name;

            // Get primary key value (If you have more than one key column, this will need to be adjusted)
            //string keyName = change.Entity.GetType().GetProperties().Single(p => p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(KeyAttribute), false).Count() > 0).Name;

            if (change.State == EntityState.Added)
            {
                using (coletasEntities ctx = new coletasEntities())
                {
                    foreach (var prop in change.CurrentValues.PropertyNames)
                    {
                        auditoria audit = new auditoria();

                        audit.campo = prop.ToString();
                        audit.data = DateTime.Now.Date;
                        audit.hora = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
                        audit.id_registro = 0;
                        audit.id_usuario = Global.id_usuario;
                        audit.tabela = tableName;
                        audit.tipo_operacao = (int)change.State;
                        audit.valor_antigo = "";
                        try
                        {
                            audit.valor_novo = change.CurrentValues[prop].ToString();
                        } catch
                        {
                            audit.valor_novo = "";
                        }

                        ctx.auditoria.Add(audit);
                        ctx.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }
                continue;
            }
            else if (change.State == EntityState.Deleted)
            {
                using (coletasEntities ctx = new coletasEntities())
                {
                    foreach (var prop in change.OriginalValues.PropertyNames)
                    {
                        auditoria audit = new auditoria();

                        audit.campo = prop.ToString();
                        audit.data = DateTime.Now.Date;
                        audit.hora = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
                        audit.id_registro = 0;
                        audit.id_usuario = Global.id_usuario;
                        audit.tabela = tableName;
                        audit.tipo_operacao = (int)change.State;

                        try
                        {
                            audit.valor_antigo = change.OriginalValues[prop].ToString();
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            audit.valor_antigo = "";
                        }


                        audit.valor_novo = "";


                        ctx.auditoria.Add(audit);
                        ctx.SaveChanges();
                    }
                }
                continue;
            }
            else if (change.State == EntityState.Modified)
            {
                using (coletasEntities ctx = new coletasEntities())
                {
                    foreach (var prop in change.OriginalValues.PropertyNames)
                    {
                        auditoria audit = new auditoria();

                        audit.campo = prop.ToString();
                        audit.data = DateTime.Now.Date;
                        audit.hora = DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString();
                        audit.id_registro = 0;
                        audit.id_usuario = Global.id_usuario;
                        audit.tabela = tableName;
                        audit.tipo_operacao = (int)change.State;

                        try
                        {
                            audit.valor_antigo = change.OriginalValues[prop].ToString();
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            audit.valor_antigo = "";
                        }

                        try
                        {
                            audit.valor_novo = change.CurrentValues[prop].ToString();
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            audit.valor_novo = "";
                        }

                        if (audit.valor_antigo != audit.valor_novo)
                        {
                            ctx.auditoria.Add(audit);
                            ctx.SaveChanges();
                        }
                    }
                }
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                // Otherwise, don't do anything, we don't care about Unchanged or Detached entities
            }
        }
        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Any sugestions?

Comment: `string tableName = tableAttr != null ? tableAttr.Name : change.Entity.GetType().BaseType.Name;` you're recording the BaseType's name, not the Entity type

Comment: & I'm failing to understand your second question and what context it applies to in your code.  I'd recommend looking into how to create an [MCV](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: About my sencond question: after inserting a new record I wanna audit this with the new generated ID number.

Answer (score 0):

Use this **auditEntry.TableName = entry.Metadata.Relational().TableName;**
following is an example:

```
       foreach (var entry in ChangeTracker.Entries())
        {
            if (entry.Entity is Audit || entry.State == EntityState.Detached || 
            entry.State == EntityState.Unchanged)
                continue;

            var auditEntry = new AuditEntry(entry);
            auditEntry.TableName = entry.Metadata.Relational().TableName;
            auditEntries.Add(auditEntry);

            foreach (var property in entry.Properties)
            {
                if (property.IsTemporary)
                {
                   
                    auditEntry.TemporaryProperties.Add(property);
                    continue;
                }

                string propertyName = property.Metadata.Name;
                if (property.Metadata.IsPrimaryKey())
                {
                    auditEntry.KeyValues[propertyName] = property.CurrentValue;
                    continue;
                }

                switch (entry.State)
                {
                    case EntityState.Added:
                        auditEntry.NewValues[propertyName] = property.CurrentValue;
                        break;

                    case EntityState.Deleted:
                        auditEntry.OldValues[propertyName] = property.OriginalValue;
                        break;

                    case EntityState.Modified:
                        if (property.IsModified)
                        {
                            auditEntry.OldValues[propertyName] = property.OriginalValue;
                            auditEntry.NewValues[propertyName] = property.CurrentValue;
                        }
                        break;
                }
            }
        }



















  public class AuditEntry
    {
        public AuditEntry()
        {
            Changes = new List<AuditDelta>();
        }

        public AuditEntry(EntityEntry entry)
        {
            Entry = entry;
            Changes = new List<AuditDelta>();
        }

        public string CreateUser { get; set; }
        public string ActionMessage { get; set; }
        public string ActionType { get; set; }
        public EntityEntry Entry { get; }
        public string TableName { get; set; }
        public int ModuleType { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, object> KeyValues { get; } = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        public Dictionary<string, object> ForeignKeyValues { get; } = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        public Dictionary<string, object> OldValues { get; } = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        public Dictionary<string, object> NewValues { get; } = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        public Dictionary<string, object> EnitityNameLabels { get; } = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        public List<PropertyEntry> TemporaryProperties { get; } = new List<PropertyEntry>();

        public bool HasTemporaryProperties => TemporaryProperties.Any();


        public List<AuditDelta> Changes { get; set; }
        public string DateTimeStamp  { get; set; }
        public AuditTrail ToAudit()
        {
            var audit = new AuditTrail();
            audit.tablename = TableName;
            audit.actiontype = ActionType;
            audit.CreateUser = CreateUser;
            audit.moduletype = ModuleType;
            audit.actionmessage = ActionMessage;
            audit.CreateDate = DateTime.UtcNow;
            audit.primarykeyvalues = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(KeyValues);
            audit.foreignkeyvalues = ForeignKeyValues.Count == 0 ? null : JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ForeignKeyValues);
            audit.oldvalues = OldValues.Count == 0 ? null : JsonConvert.SerializeObject(OldValues);
            audit.newvalues = NewValues.Count == 0 ? null : JsonConvert.SerializeObject(NewValues);

            audit.enititynamelabels = EnitityNameLabels.Count == 0 ? null : JsonConvert.SerializeObject(EnitityNameLabels);

            audit.changes = Changes.Count == 0 ? null : JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Changes);
            return audit;
        }


    }

 public class AuditDelta
    {
        public string FieldName { get; set; }
        public string ValueBefore { get; set; }
        public string ValueAfter { get; set; }
        public int FieldId { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: where is this coming frmo ? entry.Metadata.Relational().TableName

Comment: It's it coming from Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking class.